# C# All WPF controls using a common event in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls

I have created a custom WPF control like this:

[image: Custom WPF Button]

I placed this WPF control in my Form1 (Windows Form) and wrote a event MouseEnter for it. What I expect here is to get the name of the button inside WPF control. I did it with only 1 WPF control in Form1. But I have 24 WPF controls in Form1. I used **foreach** to loop through all **ElementHost** (WPF controls) and cast the child of each **ElementHost** to WPF control. I have an issue to cast ElementHost to WPF controls.

Here is my code:

```
   public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (ElementHost c in this.Controls)
            {        

                     TP1WPFControls.TP1CustomButton bt = c.Child as TP1CustomButton;

                    bt.bt.MouseEnter += Bt_MouseEnter;    
                    bt.bt.MouseLeave += Bt_MouseLeave;
            }

            //TP1WPFControls.TP1CustomButton btnCustom = elementHost1.Child as TP1CustomButton;
            //btnCustom.bt.Click += Bt_Click;
            //btnCustom.bt.MouseEnter += Bt_MouseEnter; ;
            //btnCustom.bt.MouseLeave += Bt_MouseLeave; ;

        }
```

And this is my picture to show the WPF controls in Form1:
[image]

Hope everyone can give me a solution for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the form controls, but not all of them are element hosts:

Each Windows Forms control is based off of System.Windows.Forms.Control including ElementHost.  So, in the loop, you try to cast to that.  If it's not null, you know its an ElementHost, then you can do your code on the ElementHost.

```
foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control e in this.Controls)
{        

    ElementHost c= e as ElementHost;
    if ( c != null ) 
    {
        TP1WPFControls.TP1CustomButton bt = c.Child as TP1CustomButton;
        if ( bt != null )
        {
                // Add Events (I'd assume it would just be bt.MouseEnter but I don't know what your control looks like)
                bt.bt.MouseEnter += Bt_MouseEnter;    
                bt.bt.MouseLeave += Bt_MouseLeave;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I have no error now but only the first WPF control can use the events. The second has no effect.

Comment: does your element host contain multiple buttons in it...that code would be different

Comment: In WPF control I have a label (on the left side) and a button (on the right side) call "bt"

Comment: how many wpf controls are in the element host though...is it 1 per?...is it multiple element hosts with 1 in each...or 1 element host with multiple buttons in it...that would change the code

Comment: Yes foreach loop only get the first WPF control in Form1, 1 element host have 1 label and 1 button like the picture i sent at the top of the topic

Comment: can you please include the initializecomponent and the button event code?

Comment: you tried to recommend changing my answer to include the button events...but that should be in the question...i noticed your button events are incorrect...they should be using casting the sender

Comment: I can cast the sender with Windows Form controls. But this is the first time I use WPF so I was confused. Can you give me more information to cast the sender of WPF?

Comment: can you please make the button click code available in your question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @Ctznkane525. I tried to cast the sender in MouseLeave and MouseEnter event to the type of each control in WPF custom control and It has worked! Because my TPCustomButton is just an WPF control so I have to cast each control inside it for each event above.

I have edited my answer for full information:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                ElementHost e = c as ElementHost;
                if (e != null)
                {

                    TP1WPFControls.TP1CustomButton btWPF = e.Child as TP1CustomButton;
                    if (btWPF != null)
                    {

                        //bt.bt.MouseLeave += Bt_MouseLeave;
                        //bt.lbl.MouseLeave += Lbl_MouseLeave;
                        btWPF.MouseLeave += Bt_MouseLeave;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
   private void Bt_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            TP1CustomButton btCustom = sender as TP1CustomButton;


            brushcolor = new brushColor(mediaColor.FromRgb(221, 247, 190));
            btCustom.bt.Background = brushcolor;
            btCustom.lbl.Background = brushcolor;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks I marked your answer. Your solution gave me alot ideas to make more WPF custom controls.